# Heap size Vs Time spent on garbage collection [JAVA]

Tags: java, garbage-collection, heap-memory

I wonder whether or not GC time will always be guaranteed to reduce if the heap size is set to be higher.

Thanks!

Comment: I think he just forgot to phrase this as a question...Will GC time be guaranteed to be reduced if the heap size is set to be higher? my answer= I have no idea.

Comment: I believe it's to the contrary. You might have fewer GC runs but each run might take longer to complete because of the increased number of objects to collect, that is a direct result of increasing the heap.

Comment: No, there is no such guarantee in the [Java Virtual Machine specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/) so whether this is true or not depends on the JVM implementation you are using. And this is probably not true for Oracle's JVM, and also not for other JVM implementations.

Answer (score 0):

No, it does not.

What you really care about is the old generation delays (Stop-The-World events). Take CMS for example, increasing the heap you will delay the garbage collection in the old generation, but when it happens it will take a lot of time, since your old generation is big. It takes about 1 second per GB for the CMS **this still has to be measured**.

Many applications do this kind of things though (personal experience); i.e. increase the heap.

**Why?**

Well because we could push the old generation collection towards the night in this way, when the application was used by 0.02% of total usage/users.